# AngularJS: Not performing OPTIONS method for CORS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

According to CORS explained in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), a request with method `OPTIONS` must be performed in order for the browser to check the permissions of the server..

I am simply making request using `$http` service to a different server hosted in a different machine, just because it's in a different host than the page the request must be preflighted according to CORS.. but i am getting on the logs that this is not being performed somehow

app.js

```
var restful = angular.module("ngRestful", []);

restful.config(["$httpProvider", function($http){
    $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;

    delete $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
}]);

restful.service("$rest", ["$http", function($http){
    this.get = function(url){
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: url
        });
    };
}]);
```

controller.js

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("test", ["ngRestful"]);

    app.controller("testController", ["$rest", function($rest){
        $rest.get("http://192.168.1.108/tree/server/accounts")
            .then(function(response){
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.error(err);
            });
    }]);
})();
```

i have seen on other codes that `$http.defaults.useXDomain` must be set on true in order to enable CORS.. the server gives all CORS settings on method `OPTIONS` but yet the browser is not requesting a method `OPTIONS`, of course the browser ignores the body due to not having the CORS headers in the response

Comment: If it is a *simple* request, then that wont trigger OPTIONS pre flight request. In your case, its simple request - which means no custom headers set, content-type is default/is one of those allowed content-types. Try adding content-type :application/json and that will trigger preflight (OPTIONS) request. Thus said, I dint get the issue you are facing, are you getting any error or why specifically are you looking for pre flight request

Comment: hi @Developer. The browser returns this error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.108/tree/server/accounts. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access`

Comment: This means, you have to enable CORS in your service.

Comment: To handle CORS issue in development mode, it's suggested to use proxy. Optionally, you can open your APIs to all requests. If you go the proxy way, this link might help: http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Comment: @Developer.. so all methods should have CORS settings?

Comment: We enable CORS at Verb level like GET, POST, DELETE, PUT etc and to the domains which the service should be open etc. There are few headers you should set in the response headers so that your browser will check and show you the data. I'm currently posting it from my mobile, otherwise I would have given more info. Just for your info, it's not the server who blocks the data, it's your browser who is restricting data if the response is from another domain